# Is it thread safe to use DbContext in Blazor server referencing it as injected?

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server app using Entity Framework Core. Like pretty much every example ever for this, I do the following:

```
[Inject]
private TrackingDbContext TrackingDbContext { get; set; } = default!;
```

And then when I need to do something on the database call:

```
TrackingDbContext.Users.Add(appUser);
_ = await TrackingDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The thing is, DbContext is not thread safe and is supposed to be created, used, disposed. But [the documentation I found for `AddDbContextFactory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontextfactory?view=efcore-7.0) says:

> The lifetime with which to register the factory and options. The
> default is Singleton.

Do I need to be specifying a lifetime of transient? Or is this set to transient already for Blazor? There's little documentation I can find about this and with all examples I find working as above, I'm guessing this is ok. But better to ask and be sure.

Comment: Main problem with Blazor Server that it creates Scope per connected user, so it is better to inject `IDbContextFactory` and dispose context by yourself. And factory registration should be Singleton. I do not understand why it is hard to find documentation for that, even ChatGPT(Bing) can explain everything. [Scoped dependencies](https://blazor-university.com/dependency-injection/dependency-lifetimes-and-scopes/scoped-dependencies/)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I tried ChatGPT too and it said scope is only a problem if using the DbContext in multiple threads. So using one instance long term, no problem but not thread safe. And most everything else just assumes you use `AddDbContextFactory()`. I like to triple check when it looks like what is in all the examples may be wrong.

Comment: Is this an example, or are are you injecting the single DBContext directly into your components?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I add it as a service in program.cs and then access it as above in components.

Comment: From what I've seen on your recent other questions this is a big application "This is a lot more complicated than any past multi-tenant app I've written".  Have you considered building a structured data pipeline that you can write unit tests for?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis That's on the list. But I first try to fully understand how I should use these objects because depending on testing to find if I misused something is problematic at best.

Comment: OK, ask if/when you want pointing to some resources.  I'm not a great believer in testing, but it's great for testing functionality in the core domain code and the data pipeline.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thanks - when it comes time to beat the snot out of the app, I'll be asking around that. There are those very nasty bugs that only show up when you have several hundred simultaneous requests.